# EC2 - editing .bashrc causes terminal to hang and checks to fail

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, shell, ubuntu-12.04, bashrc

I've been testing this for the past few hours with no luck.  When launching an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 micro instance, I SSH to it, create a new user and continue with installing Ruby version manger under the new user

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

This writes the following to `/home/user/.bashrc`

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

These lines are also needed in `/home/user/.bashrc` to persist the shell configuration

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

After I add the lines to `/home/user/.bashrc`, I'm still able to perform tasks under `/home/user` however if switching to root then back to `/home/user`, the terminal hangs.  I also noticed on a fresh instance, after editing `.bashrc` then rebooting the instance, the AWS console shows an alert under `Status Checks` that reads `1/2 checks passed`.

I'm not sure what the problem is, any suggestions?

Comment: That last line belongs in `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`. `rvm` will put it there itself, if you installed it correctly.

Comment: Use `set -x` in your .bashrc to see what's going on.

Comment: @Michael Hampton - Thanks, the guide I was using is a little outdated

Comment: You don't need to (and should not) edit those files yourself, nor create a `.profile` file. The "guide" you should be using is at http://rvm.io/rvm/install :)